# MS Reporting Services

Tags: sql, ssrs, reporting

We are setting up a two MS 2008 servers to handle our web application.  On server A, we are running MS SQL 2008 Web Edition with our database.  On server B, we are running IIS, MS SQL 2008 Web Edition with just MS Reporting Services.  When I trying to make the Reporting service connection from Server B to Server A, I got "The feature: "Remote access to report data sources and/or the report server database" is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services."  Does anyone know which version of MS SQL will make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Standard or higher. Or Developer (for testing); see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx).